# How to invite your facebook friends to like a page in windows phone application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, facebook-like

I try to implement an windows phone application.In some part of the application I need to invite my all facebook friends to like a facebook page.But I don't have any idea about how can I do this.

Comment: You can use facebook api for this. Check the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you cannot invite friends to like a Page with the API (it would be pretty spammy anyway). The best way to do this in a serious way:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

(post the Page on your own wall so your friends can see it)

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

(send the Page URL to specific friends)

I am not sure how to do Facebook Dialogs in a Windows Phone App though, there are Native Plugins for Android and iOS to cover them. Maybe this link helps: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows-phone-sample

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I will try.